# Low Power Toroidal Conductivity Sensor Inconsistent Values

Tags: sensor, oscillator, inductive, conductivity, toroidal

I have been trying to build a low power toroidal liquid conductivity sensor using the principle given in this image. [image: Principle of toroidal conductivity sensor]

[This](https://www.emerson.com/documents/automation/application-data-theory-application-of-conductivity-en-68442.pdf) link has more information about the principle behind the sensor.

What I have done so far -

1. For the AC analyzer voltage, I'm using a Wien Bridge Oscillator circuit built with an op amp. [Sine wave of +-3V/6V peak-peak, 4kHz frequency]
2. Using ferrite core toroids with approx. 50 turns for both the drive and receive coils. These toroidal inductors are placed in a sealed plastic enclosure.
3. I'm connecting the pickup coil voltage across a 100Ohm resistor and amplifying this voltage using an instrumentation amplifier for a gain of about 50 times. [AD620] Then the output from this amplifier goes to my scope where I monitor the AC RMS value.

I have attached the schematic for my AC analyzer.

My problem -
I have two test solutions prepared by dissolving common salt in tap water. One that reads 1.160g/ml(1) and another 1.179g/ml(2), I measured this using a hydrometer. Now when I immerse the sensor into the liquids the voltage value shoots up compared to when in air as it should. I was reading 230mV RMS for solution(1) and 280mV for solution(2). After a few more tests I noticed the reading for solution(1) shot up to 280mV and that for solution(2) went down to 260mV. Every time I pull the sensor out of the solution and put it back in the same solution values seem to fluctuate by +/-5mV around a certain value.

What potential fixes I have read about from other threads-

1. Increasing analyzer drive voltage frequency to 84kHz?
2. Using Supermalloy toroid cores instead of ferrite.
3. Using mumetal between the toroids for eliminating crosstalk.

I would like to know what is possibly causing these inconsistencies and maybe in what direction I need to proceed in to increase the repeatability of my sensor values.

Any explanation regarding this issue would be very helpful. Any explanation regarding the general theory about these sensors would be very useful as well.

If anybody has built a Toroidal Inductive sensor before then please share your thoughts and experience with me, it would be extremely helpful to me.

Schematic-
[image: Schematic]

EDIT: Photos of PCB, Toroid Enclosure and Connecting wires.
[image: PCB Photo][image: Toroid Enclosure][image]
[image]

The wires I'm using appear to have some shielding of some sort but they are not a twisted pair.

The readings I have recorded. Notice how the value for concentration 7 solution fluctuates quite a lot. This happens quite a bit. Sometimes if I give them a move it returns to something closer to the original value.
[image: Readings]

Comment: what about power supply? which one you using? can you access to osciloscope? Can you store measuring data in excel and plot it to see you sensor precision and accuracy.

Comment: I'm using a standard 5V wall wart for power supply. This gets converted to a +-5V Supply by a switched capacitor voltage converter on the PCB for the op amp which prefers a dual supply. Yes, I am using an oscilloscope for taking my readings. I have recorded it on excel, but the problem was repeatability, when I tested the same solution the next day, sometimes my readings matched that of the higher or lower conductivity solution. I am not able to find the reason for such changes in readings.

Comment: "*These toroidal inductors are placed in a sealed plastic enclosure*". Can you share a photo graph of the sensor if possible? The output will be sensitive to the *distance* between the toroids and presence of any *trapped air bubble* when you immerse it. (I assume). A photo of the wires from the circuit to the sensor can also be posted of possible. The excite and sense wires may be interacting differently if they are loose pieces of wires instead of, say, a twisted pair. Each time you move the sensor, the wires may get closer or farther from each other?

Comment: I got some idea. Use large container and position the sensor at the center to avoid magnetic leak.

Comment: I have posted pictures as you requested. The distance between the toroids is quite small maybe 0.5cm or lesser. The wires getting closer or farthar away each time I move the sensor is definitely possible, is that something I should watch out for? I have the amplifier circuit on a breadboard, I can post pictures of that too if you need it.

Comment: I have been using plastic mugs like [these](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/plastic-bathroom-mug-597197132) filled with the solution to the level where the entire plastic enclosure is immersed. How much bigger containers do you think I might need? And I also read about wall effect, since the sensor is going to be resting on the base of the plastic container do you think that might have an effect?

Comment: I have posted the readings as well. I had all the different solutions in different labeled mugs.

Comment: @Harid444  My hypothesis is position of sensor might affect result value. If you can fix the sensor in place and use same amount of water in container that might help